# Restrict users viewing post using age on database

Tags: database

Is there a way to have a birthday field on database then use the age to restrict viewing posts?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

There are probably a few ways to do this. The easiest way I can think of is to install [Pods Framework](http://pods.io/). You can install it through the WordPress repository like you'd normally install a plugin, or through GitHub. Using Pods, you can extend the WordPress user database to add a birthday field. You can also use it to extend your posts and pages by adding a custom field where you can enter your age restriction. Pods is very easy to use, and once you have everything set up, it's just a matter of editing some code in your template files to read the data. Data can be stored in separate MySQL tables, but in this case, I think the simplest way to do it is to store it as meta keys / meta values (which is the standard in WordPress).

Comment: Now what is the code to restrict posts using the birthdate field?

Comment: @JaysonPimentel - You need to research and try to solve the problem first. When that fails, show us the code you tried. Anyway, julian said: "You can also use it to extend your posts and pages by adding a custom field where you can enter your age restriction." In this case, you need to install the framework from the link above, read its documentation and then read the wordpress codex to learn about custom fields. If you still need help, present the solution you tried so people have somethin to look at. Or, hire a developer.

Comment: Leads: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+restrict+content+age&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Adults Only Age Verification http://www.bloggermint.com/2012/06/age-verification-system-for-adult-contents-on-wordpress/

Comment: Here are some additional links to get you started:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta
(to get the user's age / date of birth)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta
(to get the post's age restriction)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age
(to get age from date of birth)